# Password set in batch file not taking last character

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, psexec

I have a batch file that accept input from the user for the password. It does not take the last character for some reason and I cannot figure it out.

```
powershell -Command $pword = read-host "Enter password " -AsSecureString ; $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword) ; [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR) > .tmp.txt & set /p password=<.tmp.txt & del .tmp.txt
echo psexec \\%computerName% -u %domainName%\%userName% -p %password% cmd
```

I know it is not the powershell command because I tested it with `set /p password="Enter password: "` and still fails to echo the last character.

As per my comment, here are the if statements I used:

```
    set /P domainName=
    set params = %*:"=""?!
    if "%domainName%" == "1" (
      set "domainName=domain1"
      goto nextstep
    )
    if "%domainName%" == "2" (
      set "domainName=domain2"
      goto nextstep
    )
    if "%domainName%" == "3" (
      set "domainName=domain3"
      goto nextstep
    ) else (
      goto resetfile
    )

    :nextstep
```

My problem is that for 2 of the 3 domains, psexec runs. For domain1, it does not run. I echoed out the command, and it prints perfectly. When I remove `echo` from the command, it skips all of that and restarts the file.

`nextstep` is:

```
    :nextstep
    set /p userName="Enter your Admin username: "
    powershell -Command $pword = read-host "Enter password " -AsSecureString ; $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword) ; [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR) > .tmp.txt & set /p password=<.tmp.txt & del .tmp.txt
    psexec \\%computerName% -u %domainName%\%userName% -p %password% cmd
    :resetfile
    set resetfile=
    set /p resetfile="Do you want to restart this file? Press 'y' for Yes or 'n' for No then Press ENTER: "
    if not '%resetfile%'=='' set resetfile=%resetfile:~0,1%
    if '%resetfile%'=='y' goto start
```

The script does not even ask if I want to restart the script. It just loops back to `:start`, which is at the beginning of the script.

Please help, thank you!

Comment: I suppose the last character of the password is a special character like `&^%` or `!` and delayed expansion is enabled. Try `echo psexec.exe "\\%computerName%" -u "%domainName%\%userName%" -p "%password%" cmd`. The double quotes should be used in any case on executing `psexec.exe`. But if the password contains `%` or `!` with delayed expansion enabled, you better use  `echo psexec.exe "\\%computerName%" -u "%domainName%\%userName%" -p "!password!" cmd` with of course `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` before.

Comment: Honestly, couldn't you just run psexec from PowerShell as well, instead of doing an awful dance of getting a SecureString to be unsecure again?

Comment: @joey i suppose I can.

Answer (score 0):

Try first this with your password, to see if it's complete

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /p password=
echo my password '!password!'
```

If this still fails there must be a non ascii character involved.
Then you should change the codepage with chcp.

Then you can use it with your code

```
psexec \\%computerName% -u %domainName%\%userName% -p !password! cmd
```

Comment: You don’t need `EnableDelayedExpansion` unless setting and reading the variable happens in the same block (`if`, `for`).

Comment: @Melebius Try it without delayed expansion and my default password `^1&"&`, then you know why you want to use delayed expansion

Comment: @jeb @Melebius I actually had `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` in my file, but I removed it, and it was fine. Now, my problem is that for 2 of the 3 domains in the script, the file runs the psexec comamd. However, for one domain, it does not work. I may need to ask a new question. I echoed out the psexec command and it prints correctly. No spelling errors whatsoever. I'll add the if statements I used in the question.

Comment: @Melebius I added more information about this issue in the question. Please help, thank you so much!